# Difference between "bathe" and "shower"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice

My native English friends often use both of them but I have no idea what they mean by "bathe" and "shower". I take them to mean the same thing. They have other meanings as well, but I mean the act in which you throw water over yourself and make yourself clean.

One of the definitions of "shower" in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shower) is:

> to take a shower:
> I shower every morning.

And for "[bathe](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bathe)":

> to wash someone, usually with soap and water in a bathtub:
> I had to change the kids’ diapers and feed them and bathe them.

I am really confused. Can anyone clarify

1. "bathe" vs "shower"
2. take a bath vs take a shower

?

Comment: On EL&U a question of mine about the actual [verb "to bath"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206047/to-bath-vs-to-bathe)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the dictionary definition for "shower" includes a picture of a shower head, which clearly identifies the difference between a bathtub and a shower. In English it is very common for nouns to be used as verbs, and I see no possible confusion between the two different forms of washing oneself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Sure vote to close the question, but just to let you know, the difference between them could be subtle to any native speaker, and I'm sure you're a native speaker of English. But if you put yourself in my (non-native speaker) shoes, you will see how difficult and perplexing it is to identify the difference between both the words.

Comment: This is disappointing that native speakers think that the difference is subtle, but they are native speakers of the language. They don't have the experience of being a non-native speaker of the language. I cannot explain how hard it is to distinguish between the closely related terms in a second language.

Comment: I don't think it's that subtle. You bathe in a container of still water, you shower under a shower of falling water!

Comment: @KateBunting I don’t think it’s that simple. For example, “People who don’t bathe regularly smell bad.”

Comment: The OP in a comment said `so I still don't know what to use for the way I bathe/ shower.` so why did they accept Michael Harvey's answer?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because that seemed the best answer so far. If you had a better answer than that, you could have posted it. I have also accepted many answers (not only here but other SE sites too) that didn't satisfy me.

Comment: You're under no obligation to accept any answer that does not fully addressed your concerns. You're actually doing a diservice to visitors and users alike by accepting answers that do not satisfy you, it actively discourages people from posting additional answers.

Comment: An accepted answer tells the community that the asker (the OP)  considers it to be the best and the one that solved their problem.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I feel really awkward but I have removed the check mark from Michael Harvey's answer. Should I wait for other answers?

Comment: You should edit your question and explain why none of the answers fully satisfy you. Because, I do not know where your confusion lies and I suspect (but I could be mistaken) neither do the other users who posted.

Comment: You might find this discussion on [meta] helpful... [Not so fast! (When should I accept an answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161)

Comment: I think this should be reopened. The distinction is not as simple as tub vs shower head.

Answer (score 2):

A shower is a kind of bath:

[American Heritage Dictionary "shower"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shower)

1. intransitive verb: To wash oneself in a shower.
2. Noun
   a. A bath in which the water is sprayed on the bather in fine streams from a showerhead, usually secured overhead: take a shower.
   b. The stall or tub in which such a bath is taken.

While a shower is a kind of bath, and showering is a kind of bathing, usually **to bathe** mean to wash oneself while sitting in a **bathtub**.
**To shower** mean
s to wash oneself while standing under a fall of water in a **shower**.

Answer (score -1):

"Bathe" or "take a bath" practically universally means to wash by filling a tub and lie down in it to submerse yourself in hot water.

"Shower" or "take a shower" means to wash by standing underneath a device which sprinkles (or pours) water over you from a height.

"Bathe" can also mean to indulge in the recreational activity whereby you go into the sea to paddle or swim or just generally splash around for fun. Or a river or a lake, but (at least in the UK, where there is a coastline within a short drive of everywhere) usually the sea.

Comment: What happens with "take a shower"? Personally, I think the OP has already answered their question, the difference is clearly explained in the dictionary definitions. It's even got a picture of a shower head.

Comment: Seriously, I need to answer what "take a shower" means? Sorry, life's too short to waste on things that are *that* trivial.

Comment: (Sorry, couldn't reply earlier) Good, then we agree. The question is trivial and the answer is already contained in the question. Vote to close the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure the question is trivial to you, but not to me. I couldn't see how the answer was contained in my question. Also you have voted to close it yourself (you can even downvote if it please), but telling others to vote and close is **ill-mannered**. I don't see how my question is trivial, if others thought it was trivial, someone else would have voted to close, but theres only one close vote. And the answer wasn't present in my question because the way I bathe/ shower is still different from those provided by the answers so I still don't know what to use for the way I bathe/ shower.

Comment: @Sphinx You either sit in a tub of water and more-or-less immerse yourself (in which case you "take a bath" or "bathe"), or you stand (or possibly sit) under a device which sprinkles you with water (in which case you "(take a) shower") or you do neither (e.g. you rub yourself with a wet soapy cloth, perhaps), in which case you just "wash (yourself)".

Comment: @Sphinx it was Prime mover who replied to my request to define "take a shower" as `Seriously, I need to answer what "take a shower" means? Sorry, life's too short to waste on things that are that trivial.` the term "trivial" was not originally mine.

Comment: Added the details of what a shower is. Sorry, for some reason I thought that had been defined already in the context of the question, I thought it was only the "bath" or "bathe" bit that had not been understood.